# Why doesn't ExpressJS middleware execute synchronously

Tags: node.js, express, server

I was reading this tutorial https://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2014/03/10/express-js-middleware-demystified/ and it said that you have to call next() for express to know a function is done executing because it is asynchronous. Why not just eliminate next() and making everything synchronous instead?
(sorry...noob question)

Answer (score 1):

Because some (or possibly many) middleware do i/o operations (e.g. querying a database, writing to a log file, buffering large stream inputs, etc), and the way Node scales is by doing async operations to not block the processor while waiting for those things to occur.  It allows a single node process to handle far more concurrent requests than it might otherwise.